# Update output from user input and asynchronous server-side API calls

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vue.js, server-side, client-side

I am developping a web application.

At some point, I have an input field where the user can enter a number. Right next to it, I would like to show as an output the double of that number. Of course, that can be done easily client-side using Javascript in the following way (jQuery syntax):

```
$(document).on("change", "#input", function () {
   var x = $("#input").val();
   var y = 2 * x;
   $("#output").val(y);
});
```

However, for various reasons linked with the real application, I **need** to perform the computation server-side and show the result client-side after calling my API. My naive approach was to implement it in the following way (jQuery syntax):

```
$(document).on("change", "#input", function () {
   $("#output").val("Currently computing result");
   $.ajax({ ... }).done(function (result) {
     $("#ouput").val(result);
   });
});
```

Each time the user updates the field, an event gets triggered and an asynchronous AJAX query is sent. Each time a result comes back, the output field is updated. However, if the network is slow, or the server-side computations are multi-threaded and take random time, there is no guarantee that the results come back in the same order as the successive changes made by the user. In the end, it can happen that an inconsistent result is shown.

I expect that this is a typical situation. How can I solve it? Should I be using a front-end framework like **Vue.js** (despite the fact that I still want to host the computation server-side)? Do front-end frameworks generally handle this difficulty? Is there a simple way to handle it using plain Javascript? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can put loader to prevent user actions(ajax calls) until the response of current ajax call will not be come:

```
$(document).on("change", "#input", function () {
   // Show loader
   $("#output").val("Currently computing result");
   $.ajax({ ... }).done(function (result) {
     $("#ouput").val(result);
     // Hide loader
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, my concern is not about the failure of a query, but about the relative order in which the asynchronous queries are finished and update the output value. Your answer does not seem to handle this problem?

Comment: Ohh ok In this scenario, you can use preloader to prevent user actions(ajax calls) until the response of current ajax call will not be come.

Comment: I see. However, that does not seem like a good UX to prevent the user from typing while I am updating the output? Say he wants to type "1234", I will be sending 4 API queries : "1", "12", "123", "1234", with each query disabling the UI while I fetch the output? It seems like loosing the point of asynchronous calls no?